# Differences in using a "through" table without or with a related name for many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

When it comes to Many-To-Many fields in Django, what is the difference between using a "through" table like the following...

```
class A(models.Model):
    things = models.ManyToManyField("B", through=ThroughModel)
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    ...

class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

compared to just specifying a related name in the intermediary table like so?

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    ...

class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="things")
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Either way you should be able to reference the relationship like

```
a_instance.things
```

right? Is there some behind the scenes difference between how this is implemented in the database?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but in the first example you go from `A` to `B` while in the second `a_instance.things` will return a `ThroughModel` instance.

Comment: Oooohhhh ok. I feel silly now. So if I'm understanding correctly, these are probably the same implementation in the database, but the reference is different on the django model side when traversing the relationship from A to B -- as pointed out by @Selcuk.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in how you reference `a_instance` from `b_instance`:

```
b_instance.a_set
```

in the first case and

```
b_instance.things
```

in the second case